# Behaviour of noexcept in a class method declarator

Tags: c++, c++11, standards, language-lawyer, noexcept

What's the expected behavior of the following code?
With GCC the output is 0, whereas with clang it's 1.
Which one is correct?

```
#include <iostream>

static const bool ne = false;

struct a
{
        a() noexcept(ne) {}
        static const bool ne = true;
};

int main()
{
        std::cout << noexcept(a()) << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're both right! It's just ill-formed code. From [[basic.class.scope]](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.scope.class#1):

> A name N used in a class S shall refer to the same declaration in its context and when re-evaluated in
>   the completed scope of S. No diagnostic is required for a violation of this rule.

This section also includes the example:

> *[Example:*
>
> ```
> typedef int c;
> enum { i = 1 };
>
> class X {
>     char v[i];      // error: i refers to ::i
>                     // but when reevaluated is X::i
>     int f() { return sizeof(c); } // OK: X::c
>     char c;
>     enum { i = 2 };
> };
> [...]
> ```
>
> *-end example ]*

Without the global scope `ne`, the code is valid - but gcc fails to compile it because of [bug 70142](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=70142) (unconfirmed still).

Comment: The only compiler that runs the standard example is Clang (tried a few), and clang says the size of v is 1 (and if I understood correctly it should be 2 after it has been re evaluated). The rest of the compilers won't compile due to redefinition of i.

Comment: @José The code is ill-formed. There's no "correct" value.